# Example of cont. map. $\psi: \mathbb{R}_l \to \mathbb{R}_l$ such that $ \phi: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $, def. by $ \phi(x)=\psi(x) $, is not cont.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, sorgenfrey-line

$ \mathbb{R}_l $ denotes the Sorgenfrey line or the Lower limit topology generated by the half-open intervals $ [a,b) $ and $ \mathbb{R} $ denotes the usual euclidean topology in $ \mathbb{R} $. Can someone help me to find a continuous mapping $\psi: \mathbb{R}_l \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}_l$ such that $ \phi: \mathbb{R}\longrightarrow \mathbb{R} $, defined by $ \phi(x)=\psi(x) $, is not continuous? I can't find the same question here on this site, and I have a hard time coming up with any mapping myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\phi(x)=1$ if $x\geq 0$ and $\phi(x)=0$ if $x<0.$

For any $S\subset \mathbb R_l$ we have $$\phi^{-1}S\in \{\emptyset, \mathbb R_l, [0,\infty), (-\infty,0)\},$$ so $\phi^{-1}S$ is Sorgenfrey-open, and $\phi$ is Sorgenfey-continuous. But $\phi$ is obviously not $\mathbb R$-continuous.

Remark: It is not necessary to use a different symbol ($\psi$) for the function when considered as a function on $\mathbb R.$ It's the same function as $\phi.$

Remark: This is the same idea as in the answer by Dejan Govc, which seems to have generated a lengthy discussion.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this. For instance, you can notice that $\mathbb R_l$ is disconnected, since $(-\infty,0)\cup[0,\infty)$ is a separation. In particular, there is a surjective continuous map $\mathbb R_l\to\{0,1\}$. Compose this with an injective map $\{0,1\}\to\mathbb R_l$ and you are done.

Comment: The surjective map you are suggesting must be constant in order to be continuous, right? But I am still not getting it. What can the injective map look like? The composite map $ \psi(x)=g\circ f(x) $ must be such that $ \psi ^{-1}([a,b))=[c,d) $ for some $ c\le d $, right? Or do I think all wrong?

Comment: @GjermundJohansen: No, the surjective map does not have to be constant. Namely, map $(-\infty,0)$ to $0$ and $[0,\infty)$ to $1$. This is continuous (consider the preimages of open sets). The injective map can be anything you want.

Comment: Aha, I think I get it. But why go via $ \{0,1\} $? Can't I just define $ \psi $ to take $ (-\infty,0) $ to $ [0,1) $, say, and $ (0,\infty) $ to $ [2,3) $? I can see this is continuous in $ \mathbb{R}_l $ since the preimage of open sets are open, but how can I argue that it is not continuous in $ \mathbb{R} $? Neither $ [0,1) $ nor $ [2,3) $ are open in $ \mathbb{R} $, so there are no preimages of open sets to consider.

Comment: @GjermundJohansen: No need to go via $\{0,1\}$. Yes, you can define $\psi$ in the way you are proposing, but note that specifying where $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ are mapped is not enough to define a map. You could define for instance $$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}0;&x\in(-\infty,-1),\\x+1;&x\in[-1,0),\\2;&x\in[0,2),\\3-\frac{1}{x-1};&x\in[2,\infty).\end{cases}$$ This maps $(-\infty,0)$ to $[0,1)$ and $(0,\infty)$ to $[2,3)$. In addition to this, it solves your problem. However, there are simpler ways, take for instance $$\psi(x)=\begin{cases}x;&x<0\\x+1;&x\geq0.\end{cases}$$ This also works.

Comment: To show that these two maps $\psi$ are continuous, it is sufficient to show that $\psi^{-1}[a,b)$ is open for all $a<b$, since the intervals $[a,b)$ are a basis for the Sorgenfrey topology. You can also use the fact that $\{(-\infty,-1),[-1,0),[0,2),[2,\infty)\}$ and, in the second case, $\{(-\infty,0),[0,\infty)\}$ are finite closed covers.

Comment: I can see that those $\psi$ that you defined are continuous in $\mathbb{R}_l$, but why are they not continuous in $\mathbb{R}$? Using real analysis it is obvious that it is not continuous, but I can't do that, can I? Don't I need to find an open set in $\mathbb{R}$ having closed preimage? And that does not seem to be the case here...

Comment: @GjermundJohansen: You can use real analysis, unless someone forbids you from doing so. The notion of continuity is the same here. But yes, you can also find an open subset whose preimage is not open. (Note: this does **not** automatically mean that the preimage has to be closed **(!)**. Sets can be open, closed, both or neither.) For the two functions $\psi$ defined above, we have $\psi^{-1}(1,\infty)=[0,\infty)$ and $\psi^{-1}(0,\infty)=[0,\infty)$, respectively.